# In The Force Awakens is there any evidence of other Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

According to Han Solo, Luke has tried

> To train a new generation of Jedi, but fled after one of his students turned to the dark side.  That would be Ben Solo.

I’m wondering

> Who were the other students? Are any of them still alive?

My question is, is there any evidence of Jedi

> other than Ben Solo? (and of course Luke Skywalker; I'm excluding 'force-sensitive' non-Jedi like Maz Kanata. I'm specifically talking about the remainder of Luke's trainees, or survivors of the Old Republic).

Note - I don't believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112046/what-happened-to-these-trainees) **as the scope includes non-trainee Jedi**.

Comment: A riot control storm trooper with a light saber resistant weapon was deployed during a raid on civilians, and he did not even flinch when he was attacked with a light saber (not by a Jedi, but he could have not known that). So it seems the First Order is at least prepared for the possibility of surviving Jedi (the mission was killing the civilians, not containing them, so the guy certainly was not there for riot control). That's very indirect reasoning, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the opening crawl (at least, as quoted from the Novelization):

```
FIRST ORDER has risen from
the ashes of the Empire
and will not rest until
Skywalker, the last Jedi,
has been destroyed.
```

There's no canon information on anyone remaining from Luke's academy training after Kylo Ren "destroyed everything Luke worked for". There is reason to interpret canon as Kylo killing everyone off. But even if not - if some of them survived and required training, I find it unlikely that Luke would then abandon them and hide.

Comment: I think we should interpret that cautiously, as meaning something more like "the last Jedi *that the First Order knows about*".  Ezra might still be alive, for example, though presumably he won't turn up in the movies.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - fair assessment. We all know how much Lucasoids likes to stick random new Jedi all over the place. Not that I'm complaining.