# Where is Ahsoka Tano during the events of the original trilogy and beyond?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, ahsoka-tano

I was browsing SFF.SE and saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112209/in-the-force-awakens-is-there-any-evidence-of-other-jedi?rq=1). I was also recently rewatching Star Wars: The Clone Wars and a thought occurred to me. Since Ahsoka Tano was technically removed from the Jedi Order, technically she could be included within the statements commonly made by Star Wars villains about "Let's kill the last Jedi".

This is from my understanding one of the premises of Star Wars Rebels *(Please no spoilers of just Star Wars Rebels, I haven't watched it yet!)* and I had a thought.

**What happened to Ahsoka Tano during not only Episodes 4-6, but in TFA as well?**

Comment: Also note that Ahsoka does appear in *Rebels*, and there have been hints that the season 2 finale will focus on her. So we may have an answer in a few weeks

Comment: The only real answer we have right now is, "We don't know, but she's probably dead or otherwise permanently indisposed to help anyone by the time Episode 4 occurs." As @JasonBaker points out, *Star Wars Rebels* might definitively answer this question eventually. Or it might not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with the site's 'future works' policy.

Comment: @Richard Please see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed.

Comment: @Anoplexian - I can assure you that there are no canon works that deal with Ahsoka's whereabouts during the time period you've mentioned. If such a thing existed, it would be a massive spoiler for the whole of the remaining series of Rebels.

Comment: @Anoplexian - Please see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: That meta says nothing about a VTC on these questions (at least not one that currently exists). The answer that was accepted simply states that they should not be closed, but rather put on hold.

Comment: And if you VTC my question, might as well VTC this too.....http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/in-star-wars-the-force-awakens-how-could-this-lightsaber-have-turned-up-wher

Comment: @Anoplexian - Well, there's at least a partial answer to that question...http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113491/20774

Comment: But not accepted. It also doesn't actually answer the question, as it specifies where **Maz** got it, not how it escaped from Luke.

Comment: @JasonBaker Reopened. I'm taking your word for it that this is now answerable, so I hope you're right! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, Ahsoka's fate during the OT is unknown, partly because Star Wars Rebels is not concluded yet.

Since you haven't watched,  I can only say that the earliest when we may get an answer is at the end of Season 2, and that is only with one very specific outcome to one of the events spotlighted in the trailers. If that doesn't happen, that likely means we need to wait for more seasons before we will know the answer.

So at present, we do not know where Ahsoka is during the OT because her current story is not concluded and revealing her future by Disney at this point will just spoil the ending of the current story.

Comment: Ah. I've seen/watched/played all of the canon sources, but haven't touched Legends (Except SWTOR), so I wanted to know if she appeared in any Legends stories, but apparently not. +1

Comment: Most of the EU after Endor had been published before The Clone Wars series came out (George Lucas set the prequels and the Imperial era as off limits to EU authors in general, so most works are pre or post movies). By the time Ahsoka came into existence, the EU is already published to after 130 ABY.

Comment: That really clears things up!

Answer (score 3):

Its still up in the air following the season 2 finale of Star Wars: Rebels, "Twilight of the Apprentice", following on from what Jason Baker has posted, that creature flies down into the temple and we see someone in the darkness of the temple.

This is most likely Ahsoka and since we didn't see how the fight between her and Vader went she could still be alive or a force ghost (so from a certain point of view, she's alive...)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ahsoka survives the entire original trilogy: she appears in the very last scene on *Rebels* which is set after ROTJ. After that, there's no official word unless it's been mentioned in a novel or something.

As to why she doesn't appear in the trilogy itself, that's easily explained because the focus is on Luke Skywalker and his group. In the first film, the only members of the Rebellion you see are the ones on Leia's ship at the start, and then at the base at the end, and the latter for only a few hours of in-universe time. Ahsoka could easily have been somewhere else during that brief period.

In TESB she could have been on Hoth and evacuated with the others near the start, and you don't see any other rebels aside from the main characters for the rest of the film.

In ROTJ, again the first part of the film is focused on the crew on Tatooine, so no reason for Ahsoka to be there. The only times she'd have a legit reason to appear would be the Mon Mothma/Ackbar briefing prior to the mission; otherwise the rest of the film--not counting the ending scenes--is focused on the strike team on the moon, on Luke on the Death Star, on Lando (and Wedge for a few seconds), or on Ackbar on his command bridge. Ahsoka could have literally been anywhere during that battle and she never would have appeared.

And that's assuming she was there at all and not doing all sorts of other Rebel-like things somewhere else. In ROTJ, for instance, aside from the small infiltration team, it was the Rebellion naval force that was being used at Endor. Any ground forces they might have would have had no reason to be there, and she could have been off with them as, despite certainly being able to fly, she's been primarily portrayed as a ground combatant.

Comment: Presumably if they had a Jedi, they'd have had them in the strike team or somewhere prominent.